# Assign Role to User, use UUID as primary key for all tables

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, uuid, roles

I am using UUID as primary key for all tables. When I am assigning the role to user return this

error:
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a c hild row: a foreign key constraint fails (`leave_management`.`model_has_roles`, CONSTRAINT` model_has_roles_role_id_foreign `FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES` roles `(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into` model_has_roles `(`model_id
`,` model_type`,` role_id`) values (17a97eae-45c8-49b4-9985-453e2e2d50be, App\Models\User, 0))`

User and Roles have keys but same error.

role table screenshot [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZa8g.png).

user table screenshot [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxtku.png)

Comment: Are you inserting in the right order? You must insert the user first or the role won't have a user to refer to.

Comment: First add role then create user then assign role

Comment: That looks like a Laravel fillable error. Have you added protected $fillable to your model?

Comment: why your role_id is 0?

Comment: This is working like this ```$superAdmin = \App\Models\User::create([
            'name' => 'Super-Admin',
            'email' => 'superadmin@test.com',
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => Hash::make('Superadmin123@'),
        ]);
        $role = \App\Models\Role::where('name', 'super-admin')->get();
        $superAdmin->assignRole($role[0]);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working like this

```
       'name' => 'Super-Admin',             
       'email' => 'superadmin@test.com',             
       'email_verified_at' => now(),             
       'password' => Hash::make('Superadmin123@'),         ]);         
   $role = \App\Models\Role::where('name', 'super-admin')->get();         
  $superAdmin->assignRole($role[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in SQLSTATE error role_id that you sent in query is not a valid role id and does not exists in your roles table (it evaluates as 0 if not exists)

So you should first make sure that the role already exists

For confirming that your role is valid first dump it somewhere and make sure that it's a valid role object
It is possible that the role does not exist and the query result is null

Something like this question:
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/1144

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).